# First Android app: pictures not refreshing

Tags: android

im very new to Java and Android Programming and am currently trying to write my first Android App. 
The App shows 3 Dices, and depending on what combination the dices Show, the App says "yes" "no" or "ultra yes".
My Problem is, when hitting the Button to Re-Roll, sometimes the Pictures of single Dices do not get Updated and then the Answer is wrong (i hope it is somehow clear what i mean)

In this Screenshots you can see what i mean. The first Picture everything is correct (2 dices showing the same numbers means a "No"). Then i hit the Reroll button again and somehow the Pictures didn't get updated.. This occures Randomly, sometimes it works correct 10+ times.

http://image-upload.de/image/gbYhNq/ce3ef664bd.png
http://image-upload.de/image/j8jSTv/97ed7d0f7e.png

The Code of the APP:
http://pastebin.com/360DwFcg

thanks in Advance from a newbie ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your random dice number generation is wrong. It creates a random number from one to **seven**.

This is probably a long shot, but since your answer is "ultra yes", then all three dice are the same value. So maybe you just got a lucky 7, 7, 7, in which case no images are updated. Just change your random generation to

```
(int) (Math.random() * 6 + 1)
```